# how to cache view in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I  don't seem to be able to find any information on how to cache the whole HTML page in cakephp3, anyone can help on this, I was able to do it in cakephp 1.2, if I need to cache the whole page like  url `/products/show/1`, I just declare below in a `ProductsController`, and the page will be cached

```
var $cacheAction = array( 'show' => '72 hour');
```

another question, is there a similar tag in cakephp3 that works something like `cake:nocache` in cakephp1.2

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache helper has been removed in CakePHP 3, as it wasn't a proper, generic implementation to begin with. It is recommended that you use a caching server like [**Varnish**](https://varnish-cache.org) or [**Squid**](http://www.squid-cache.org), and use [**Edge Side Includes (ESI)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes) if you need to account for dynamic content.

CDNs like Akamai, Cloudflare, etc support ESI too, or even custom implementations. For other cases check out plugins like for example [**cakephp-cache**](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-cache), or learn about the [**CakePHP request cycle**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro.html#request-cycle) and [**middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html) if you want to roll your own solution.

See also

- **[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.0 Migration Guide > CacheHelper Removed](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#cachehelper-removed)**
- **[Awesome CakePHP > Caching](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#caching)**

Comment: it is a pity to remove the cache helper, it reduces the complexity of the implementation of caching, really increase performance and flexibility of not caching certain part of web view. I really can't find anything above that excel in all these together. feels to me it is a step backward.